# Want create a View that come from upperside at some position

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

I have created View which displays at position `(0, 0, 320, 100)`. Now I want to make that view to come from upperside and to be set at given position I have tried this.

```
CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
     transition.duration = 1.0;
     transition.type = kCATransitionFromTop; //choose your animation
     [bGView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
     [self.view addSubview:bGView];
```

But it did not worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust frames of your view in animation blocks
First add your view as subview

```
     [self.view addSubview:bGView];
```

and give it a frame outside the visible screen area

```
    bGView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-150,320,100);
```

and then fire animation to bring it from upside

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0
                animations:^{ 
                    bGView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,100);
                } 
                completion:^(BOOL finished){
                    ;
                }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Everything is ok. Except a fact that animation should be added in superview, so it should be like:

```
[self.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try view block animation

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.7f animations:^{

        bGView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0f, 200.0f, 320.0f, 100.0f);//Some frame

}];
```